# При отправке формы на сайте, в google form не отображается кириллица

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

Имеется лэндинг который стоит на github pages, собственно есть форма которая отправляет все поля через POST на мою созданную форму в Google forms.
Если заполняю поля такие как "имя" на английском, то по итогу в google forms все правильно приходит, но если заполнить русскими буквами (кириллицой), то поля в google forms просто остаются пустые как будто я туда вообще ничего не писал.

Я пробовал заполнять форму напрямую в google forms, там кириллица проходит. Соответсвенно проблема где то у меня на стороне.
Ниже форма в html и JS код. В чем может быть проблема? я предполагаю что проблема может быть в кодировке, но могу ошибаться конечно, да и как это решить понятие не имею.

```
<form id="contactform" class="contacts__form" method="POST" action="https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeKf4rD2-8Cg5-lFsljLOXHh4V_WdoPGfom7Ds6Yz5Cgt67HA" onsubmit="return window.submitGoogleForm(this);">
                    <div class="contacts__input">
                        <input required name="entry.2005620554" id="name" type="text">
                        <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contacts__input">
                        <input required name="entry.1045781291" id="email" type="email">
                        <label for="email">Ваша почта</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contacts__textarea">
                        <textarea name="entry.839337160" id="text"></textarea>
                        <label for="text">Ваше сообщение</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contacts__triggers">
                        <button class="btn contacts__btn">
                            Отправить сообщение
                        </button>
                        <footer class="contacts__policy">
                            <input required type="checkbox">
                            <span class="subtitle subtitle_fz12">Я согласен(а) с <a href="/portfolio/dist/policy.html" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a></span>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

вот тут JS

```
!function(exports) {
exports.submitGoogleForm = submitGoogleForm;

function submitGoogleForm(form) {
    try {
    var data = [].slice.call(form).map(function(control) {
        return 'value' in control && control.name ?
        control.name + '=' + (control.value === undefined ? '' : control.value) :
        '';
    }).join('&');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', form.action + '/formResponse', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept',
        'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type',
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(data);
    } catch(e) {}

    form.parentNode.className += ' submitted';

    return false;
}
}(typeof module === 'undefined' ? window : module.exports);
```

Выглядит по итогу проблема в google form как то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

первые два поля пришли отлично, так как они были на английском заполнены, а третье поле пришло пустым, оно заполнялось по русски.

Comment: А если третье поле заполнить английскими буквами? Что уходит с клиента?

Comment: Имеете ввиду в форме на сайте, третье поле английскими заполнить? приходит все гуд тогда в google forms, но по англ. Проблема в том, что сайт на русском, никто по англ писать не будет.